# Delete only PDF objects in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with two types of objects: Form Controls and a PDF object. I want to create a macro that will only delete the PDF object and not my Form Controls.

I currently have the following code: `ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects.Delete` However, this removes both my Form Controls and my PDF object.

How might I tweak this to selectively delete the PDF object, or delete all objects except my Form Control.

Many thanks!

For Reference: the code I use to insert my PDF Object is below..

```
Public Sub insertFile()

    'Select the cell in which you want to place the attachment
    Range("B34").Select

    'Get file path
    fpath = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files,*.*", Title:="Select file")
    If LCase(fpath) = "false" Then Exit Sub

    'Insert file
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add _
    filename:=fpath, _
    Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s4/win002.htm

Comment: `ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a clue in your existing code:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add ...
```

You just need to use a different method:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Delete
```